# How to make a data not compulsory to run my script fine (Google App Script)?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Good day,

I'm very new to programming and I'm facing an issue with a Script I paid someone to write for me.

I shared all the documents needed here : https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1KR0ujESyVRKoUS98T4ItraWoTflqVRwj?usp=sharing

Basically this script does the following :

1. Go through the column A and check if there is any checked boxes
2. If any box is checked, it selects the data of the line(s) and fill in those data in the specific places of the Google Document (template) linked to the script
3. It will convert the Google Document in PDF
4. Used the draft email we saved in Gmail and attached the PDF to it
5. Send over the email + PDF to the specific email addresses in column B
6. Check if a folder exist in the defined place, create one if it doesn't exist and classify the PDF in it or just classify the document if the folder already exists.

My issue is that if the column E (date referred as "BL" in the script) is not filled, the email is sent over without title and without PDF. I would like my script to continue running even if this info is not filled in, to leave the places where this info appears as blank.

It's the very first time that I have post on Stack Overflow so please let me know if you need more info about something. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: [mcve].........

Comment: Your question is off-topic to Stack Overflow.  You're basically asking someone to do free work for you.  In order to determine what your code needs, someone would need to do the work to debug your code.  And if someone clicks on your link, that folder and those files are automatically put into the shared folder of the person who clicks on your link.  And it's hard to remove the folder from the shared Drive if we don't want it there.

Comment: @AlanWells Hard or impossible?

Comment: The only way that I've found to remove an unwanted listing in my shared folder is to drag it to the trash bin.

Comment: Good day, 

Thank you for your answers. I actually understand how the script works / how it is built. The script works perfectly fine but I noticed that I could improve it by making this specific data not compulsory for running the script. I wanted to post my question on Stack Overflow in order to understand/learn how to do it, that would help me to build my knowledge on this script. I undertand that it's not a good way to share the documents with you via a GDrive link, what would be the best way to do it ? Thank you in advance for your help. Have a nice day.

Comment: The best way would be: [mcve]. Also, to notify specific users, use `@` like @TheMaster